# Configurable redirect URL in DocPad

Tags: docpad

I'm using DocPad to generate system documentation.   I am including release notes in the format

- http://example.com/releases/1.0
- http://example.com/releases/1.1
- http://example.com/releases/1.2
- http://example.com/releases/1.3

I want to include a link which will redirect to the most recent release.

- http://example.com/releases/latest

My question: how do I make a link that will redirect to a relative URL based on configuration?  I want this to be easily changeable by a non-programmer.

Update: I've added cleanurls into my docpad.js, similar to example below.  (see code below).  But using "grunt docpad:generate" seems to skip making the redirect (is this an HTML page?). I've a static site.  I also confirmed I'm using the latest cleanurls (2.8.1) in my package.json.

Here's my docpad.js

```
'use strict';

var releases = require('./releases.json');  // list them as a list, backwards: ["1.3", "1.2", "1.1", "1.0"]

var latestRelease = releases.slice(1,2)[0];

module.exports = {
    outPath: 'epicenter/docs/',
    templateData: {
        site: {
            swiftype: {
                apiKey: 'XXXX',
                resultsUrl: '/epicenter/docs/search.html'
            },
            ga: 'XXXX'
        },
    },
    collections: {
        public: function () {
            return this.getCollection('documents').findAll({
                relativeOutDirPath: /public.*/, isPage: true
            });
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        cleanurls: {
            simpleRedirects: {'/public/releases/latest': '/public/releases/' + latestRelease}
        },
        lunr: {
            resultsTemplate: 'src/partials/teaser.html.eco',
            indexes: {
                myIndex: {
                    collection: 'public',
                    indexFields: [{
                        name: 'title',
                        boost: 10
                    }, {
                        name: 'body',
                        boost: 1
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When I run grunt docpad:generate, my pages get generated, but there is an error near the end:

```
/data/jenkins/workspace/stage-epicenter-docs/docs/docpad/node_modules/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/node_modules/taskgroup/node_modules/ambi/es6/lib/ambi.js:5
export default function ambi (method, ...args) {
^^^^^^
```

I can't tell if that's the issue preventing this from running but it seems suspicious.

Comment: Is your website going to be deployed to a static or dynamic host?

Comment: Do you have this release information as an array somewhere that would be available to your DocPad Configuration File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that your configuration is available to the [DocPad Configuration File](https://docpad.org/docs/config), you can use the redirect abilities of the [cleanurls plugin](https://docpad.org/p/cleanurls) to accomplish this for both dynamic and static environments.

With a `docpad.coffee` configuration file, it would look something like this:

```
releases = require('./releases.json')  # ['1.0', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3']
latestRelease = releases.slice(-1)[0]

docpadConfig =
    plugins:
        cleanurls:
            simpleRedirects:
                '/releases/latest': '/releases/' + latestRelease

module.exports = docpadConfig
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a static site.  I added this in to my existing docpad config, upped the version of cleanurls in package.json to 2.81, then ran "grunt docpad:generate".  But it didn't generate the expected redirect.  Any suggestions for what else to double check?  I'm a bit of a docpad novice, having inherited someone else's code.

Comment: I do see an error when generating - could this be related?

/data/jenkins/workspace/stage-epicenter-docs/docs/docpad/node_modules/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/node_modules/taskgroup/node_modules/ambi/es6/lib/ambi.js:5
export default function ambi (method, ...args) {
^^^^^^

Comment: @WillGlass does `grunt docpad:generate` generate with the `--env static` flag? As that is necessary for the cleanurl redirect files to be outputted, otherwise it will just add them to the docpad express server, that is exposed via the `docpad run` command, rather than the `docpad generate` command (which is what I assume that grunt task is calling).

Comment: @WillGlass the ambi thing is just a warning, although it certainly does look suspicious doesn't it! The warning will be fixed up in the next few days :-)

Comment: added "--env static" and now get error.  Most likely something specific to my build, but if you are aware of a common cause of that it'd be useful.  I'm sure your answer is the way to go; I will go ahead and accept it.  In the meantime I will slim down the build to a simple test case to make it easier to test.   Here's the error: ">> TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined
>>   at DocPad.module.exports.docpadUtil.action (/data/jenkins/workspace/stage-epicenter-docs/docs/docpad/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/util.js:129:33)"

Comment: @WillGlass no worries, perhaps let's follow up on the slack https://slack.bevry.me